# How do I build a popup dialog in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, popup

I am building a Web Application using asp.net (C#). I come from windows forms development and find myself in a hard spot. Im making an application where the user should edit some simple information about himself, and thus i need to create a new dialog. How do I do that in asp.net? I have a button which event is handled serverside, and when i click lthis button i want to popup a dialog where i can show my custom web control (or any web control, lets make it generic from the start). How do I go about with doing so?

I got some part of the way by looking at the internet, that i need to make a  section and set the z-index to 1000, but how do i make it visible (block)? Please help here as i am completely lost...

/H4mm3rHead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not concerned about using a library, try [Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/), they have several controls that can create something you want (the ModalPopup control).

Comment: I second the ModalPopup control.  It brings a nice feel to the page, forcing a decision before being able to modify any more data.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX Control Toolkit has a [ConfirmButton](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) extender which will do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the following:
1. my new pop up is just a new aspx page like any other page
2. add a button (or just a link) that fires a client side java script function
3. in the function I use window.open and put params to open my popup page with no toolbars or scrollbars and proper size to its content

[check this for more info on #3](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)