# Displaying popup 

Tags: asp.net

I have a string in a masterpage which I have to display as a pop up in my application. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a popup dialog in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088918/how-do-i-build-a-popup-dialog-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-window.phtml or go with Built in AJAX capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This a pretty vague question. There is a lot of possibilities.

You can do that in Javascript. I use some jQuery to do this kind of stuff, there is a lot of possibilities using jQuery

- [jQueryPopup](http://www.jquerypopup.com/)
- [Top 10 of jQuery popups](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/10-jquery-popup-window-image-slider-plugins/)
- [Another top 15 for
  modal popups](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/)