# how to open modal popup on textbox click in c#

Tags: c#

I have a `TextBox` and and I want to open a `Popup` on clicking `TextBox`. There is no `Click` event for `TextBox`. I want to do it in C# completely. I don't need jquery in opening `Popup` on `Click` of `TextBox`.

Comment: Is it winforms or asp.net?

Comment: C# is server-side only.  To show a pop-up on the browser, you'll need to use Javascript (which is client-side).

Comment: please define full details

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a popup dialog in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088918/how-do-i-build-a-popup-dialog-in-asp-net)

Comment: Are you using Ajaxtoolkit?

Comment: i have a textbox and i need that when i click on extbox popup gets open.but there is no event for click,only textchangedevent was there.so i  not getting how toopen popup and in c# only

Comment: yesmodalpopup extender

Comment: Why do you insist on a C# solution? It's not the right tool for the job...

Comment: no there is not my answer in ur redirected page@walter

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net textbox:

```
    <asp:textbox onclick="myJavaScriptFunction()" runat="server" id="myTextBox" ... >
```

@edit

jquery example:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
     alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Comment: there isn't any jQuery in that answer

Comment: @nirmus I'm guessing that when user###### says jQuery, they mean Javascript.

Comment: is there is any soln purely in c#

Comment: @Jeremy Pridemore If you are right, I think that is not possible using only C#. You have to use javascript and send request to server. Example `http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/`. But I don't know how you want to use it to make pop up..

Comment: @user2494087 C# runs on the server. Javascript runs in the browser. You can do it in C# with a lot of hassle but then it opens the dialog on the server - I'm guessing tyhat's not what you want?

Comment: can u provide me c# solution

Comment: @user2494087  There are many different .net UI technologies.  You need to be specific with which tech you are using, e.g. winforms, WPF, windows 8, asp.net, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of creating a website solution like you are doing makes this impossible. In ASP.NET WebForms and MVC you do not deliver C# code to the user so you cannot create client side behavior with C#; instead, you deliver an HTML page and assets like files for Javascript, CSS, images, etc. If you want to invoke client side behavior, you need code that will run client side. That means using Javascript, and I recommend that you use jQuery while doing that.

nirmus's answer will give you an example for that, but to answer your question completely bluntly the answer is: "You can't."